# Can not style the navbar links bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

Here is the html

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#homenavbar">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a href="home.html" class="navbar-brand" style="padding-top: 0;margin-top: 0">Name</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="homenavbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right hidden-xs hidden-sm" id="menu">
            <li><a href="#home">HOME</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">ABOUT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#services">SERVICES</a></li>
            <li><a href="#portfolio">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
            <li><a href="#testimonial">TESTIMONIAL</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</nav>`
```

Here is the css

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
border-bottom: 3px solid green;
color: #009ddc;
}
```

but hover and focus are not working.I couldn't find the problem. Anyone please help.

Comment: cand you make a working example ?

Answer (score 1):

```css
#menu li > a:hover, #menu li:hover >a{
  color:red;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
<div class="container-fluid">
  
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right" id="menu">
            <li><a href="#home">HOME</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">ABOUT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#services">SERVICES</a></li>
            <li><a href="#portfolio">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
            <li><a href="#testimonial">TESTIMONIAL</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</nav>
```

Try this :) If you mind to do "active class" do with javascript

Comment: Thanks for your help. It was a silly mistake. It works now.

Comment: Np! Glad to help you!

Answer (score 0):

With the exception of the closing `</nav>` tag, your code is correct. I've copied and pasted your code into a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o4f6vxv4/), and the hover works fine.

Comment: Still having the problem. No effect on navbar links :( .

Comment: Does the JSFiddle I posted work for you? If not, can you tell me what browser you are using?